# Why do we always consider 2-variable affinity metrics?

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, metric

Clustering algorithms often use some affinity metrics to cluster a dataset. Given some data points $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n$, it is common to compare $x_i$ and $x_j$ using a function $f(x_i, x_j)$ which could be, for example, the norm of the difference between these two points or a Gaussian kernel.

My question is rather simple: would we gain anything by considering instead $f(x_i, x_j, x_k)$? That is, a $3$-variable affinity metric, or even a $k$-variable affinity metric? Is there a result that states that $k=2$ is optimal? Or do we usually stick to $k=2$ because it is less computationally heavy?

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few considerations, ordered via the thinking-out-loud principle. (i) Using *k=2* the resulting data object can be thought of as a (two-dimensional) matrix. We have a huge number of tools to deal with matrices. We are used to two-ary operations (addition, multiplication, inner product ..) (ii) Using *k=3* hugely increases the number of data points as you say, and there are no generalised tools that I'm aware of to deal with say a three-dimensional distance matrix. (iii) Generally *k=2* implicitly encodes a lot of information, for example if *f* is a metric distance there are strong constraints on the three values *f(x_i, x_j), f(x_i, x_k), f(x_j, x_k)*. There is scope for enormous redundancy if you consider all triples *g(x_i, x_j, x_k)* given a three-ary function *g*. (iv) my hunch is if something could be gained the likelihood is that someone would have investigated it. I struggle to find ideas for using triplets (or beyond), where the redundancy mentioned above (iii) is probably my key intuition. Supplied with a three-ary function *g(x_i, x_j, x_k)*, the first thing that comes to my mind is to simplify it into a two-ary function *f(x_i, x_j)* by holding *x_i* and *x_j* constant and integrating/averaging *g* over varying *x_k*. I am not sure that your question whether *k=2* is optimal is actually meaningful. I would first like to see at least one example of an actual three-ary function *g* that we can imagine to have some form of utility in clustering.